# Visual Studio 2015 not showing CSS properties

Tags: visual-studio, css

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. I'm interested in using it for web development, so I opened a CSS file and expected to see the CSS properties, but they are not shown, see below:

[image]

If I open the same file in Expression Web 4, the CSS properties are shown, like this:

[image]

It's this version:

[image]

Any ideas?